# Swapping void* pointers in C++

Tags: c++, swap, void, void-pointers

I wanted to ask if this kind of swapping implementation would work:

```
 void swap (void* &a, void* &b ) 
 {    
     void * tmp = a;
     a=b;
     b=tmp;
 }

int main() 
{
   void * a;
   void * b;   
   swap (a,b);
   return 0;
}
```

Do I need to somehow send the size of the object to the swap method and use it? If so, then what is a good implementation for this function?

Comment: You *have* sent the size to the swap method. You said, "here are two void pointers, please swap them". The size is `sizeof(void *)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. I'm not sure it does what you think it does: The pointer values are swapped, not whatever they point to.

Comment: what do you mean? won't a now points to whatever b pointed to and vice verse? or did you mean that they didn't change the actual value, but they only changed their address?

Comment: Imagine you have an `int *a, *b; a = new int(42); b = new int(17); swap(a, b);`, now `a` will be pointing to the memory originally allocated for `b`, and `b` will point to the memory originally allocated for `a`. In other words, the values `42` and `17` stay where they were. It depends on what you are actually trying to achieve, whether that is what you wanted or not.

Comment: What I mean is that in the following code:
    `f()
    {
        some_type x,y;
        void *a = &x, *b = &y;
        swap( a, b);
    }`
the objects x and y will not have changed (not have been swapped).
But a will now point to y and b to x.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me (a pointer is just a pointer, so the sizes of the things it's pointing to doesn't matter), but why not just use [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)?

In this example, you're messing with uninitialized variables, which is bad, but that doesn't seem to be the main point of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This function will work just fine for swapping `void` pointers; the compiler knows their size. If you want to swap something other than `void` pointers you need a different function.

EDIT: but that's the general pattern for a swap template function:

```
template <class Ty>
void swap(Ty& lhs, Ty& rhs) {
    Ty tmp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = tmp;
}
```